# npm ERR! cb() never called! when trying to create an react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to create a new reactjs aplication, but everytime I run "npx create-react-app", i get the same error:

```
npm ERR! cb() never called!
```

I've already tried to unistall node.js, update npm and the "npm cache clean --force" command but none of them worked. Can someone help? (By the way, i'm using Windows 10)

Comment: which version of node you are using? you can check it by running node -v or node --version in your cmd and please check the version of npm too. Moreover a create react app issue its an npm issue https://npm.community/t/crash-npm-err-cb-never-called/858/138

Comment: I'm using the 14.15.1 version

Comment: And npm version is 6.14.9

Comment: @Pedro Henrique Gomes - Did you get is resolved? If so, Can you share the solution here please?

Comment: Honestly, i simply installed Yarn and tried to install stuff using it. The error simply vanished, don't know why tho